# Cycling between two images

Tags: javascript

// this code is meant to create an array of two images and just circle through them to make it appear that a lightbulb is flashing on and off.

```
var imageArray = new Array();

var numImages=2;

// create new array to hold preload images; call this array imageArray   
// create (global!) variable called numImages to hold total number of images;  
//use for loop to populate imageArray    


for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
imageArray[i] = new image();
imageArray[i].src="images/brightIdea"+(i+1)+"png"
//set image src property to image path, preloading image in the process

}


var i4_circleThru = 0; // global variable ( be careful) use for the function CicleThru()

function circleThru() {

//if browser does not support the image object, exit.

//  write images, from imageArray to HTML doc

// call the setTimeout method on circleThru

}//end circleThru()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your end result is an html image, why not do it this way:

First, in your HTML:

```
<img id="imageID">
```

Then in your script:

```
var imageArray = [];
var numImages = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
  imageArray[i] ="images/brightIdea"+(i+1)+".png"
}
var i4_circleThru = 0;
var image = document.getElementById("imageId");
image.src = imageArray[i4_circleThru];

window.setInterval(function(){
  i4_circleThru = (i4_circleThru+1)%numImages;
  image.src = imageArray[i4_circleThru];
},1000);
```

A more complete example can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/FrancisMacDougall/fseswsro/